# Show the splashscreen when return from background

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hi is it possible and legally to show the splashscreen when my app return from background.. If yes.. what I have to insert into this code? Thanks

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

Comment: It will be unpleasant for users, seeing it every 2 minutes. Even if you want to do....Load the UIView having all images and text that you want to have in your splash screen.

Comment: that would happen if your application terminates when going into background. But do you want to preserve the state of your application before going into the background?

Comment: Yes I know but at the moment I've not other solutions. I need it

Comment: Yes I need to save the state of my app before going into the background

Comment: The splashscreen is loaded only when application starts, so the only method is to simulate it, putting a UIImageView to the window when application comes back from background.

Comment: It's possible to do, but why do you want to do that? Your user wants use your app, not look at a splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the same thing in few of my applications - simply add a UIImageView to window. And show it once application goes to background and fade it out after a delay :)

See this answer for more details: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967054/894671

Comment: ok thanks! But.. can UImageView appair above status bar and tab bar?

Comment: You could hide statusbar while UIImageView is visible.

Comment: Or experiment with adding a view above statusbar 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2834029/894671